# Linear Algebra , Geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Hi i have worked out the answers for this question which is (3,-5,1). Is there any ways to check whether my answers are correct ? Thanks in advance :)

[image: Question Which i solved]

Comment: For which value of $t$ do you get that answer?

Comment: i took both T values the top and the bottom and do a cross product to get the answer

Comment: The point you have obtained as the answer to the question does not lie on any line. Try $(5, 3, -1)$.

Comment: Your answer can't make sense, since from the second equation you have that $x=5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $ \vec{x}=(1,1,1)^T+t(2,1,-1)^T$ and $x=5$, we get $5=1+2t$, hence $t=2.$ This gives $y=3$ and $z=-1.$
Therefore the  point of intersectioin is

$$(5,3,-1).$$